# How to get points from polydata instance?

Tags: python, vtk

Like the code below, 
when we make an instance of vtkPolyData()(:here, polydata), 
we use SetPoints(points) to assign points. 
Then, when I want to get points(:an instance of vtkPoints()) this time,
 what should I do for polydata(:an instance of vtkPolyData())?

```
def points2actor(xyz, apoint_size):
    import vtk
    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    # Create the topology of the point (a vertex)
    vertices = vtk.vtkCellArray()
    # Add points
    for i in range(0, len(xyz)):
        p = xyz.loc[i].values.tolist()
        point_id = points.InsertNextPoint(p)
        vertices.InsertNextCell(1)
        vertices.InsertCellPoint(point_id)
    # Create a poly data object
    polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    # Set the points and vertices we created as the geometry and topology of the polydata
    polydata.SetPoints(points)
    polydata.SetVerts(vertices)
    polydata.Modified()
    # Mapper for points
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInput(polydata)
    # ACTOR for points
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    actor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(apoint_size)
    return actor, polydata
```

Answer (score 1):

`points = polydata.GetPoints()`

There is no python doc but the cpp API is the same:

- https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData-members.html
- https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPointSet.html#af8a9a39d0ff4c56454be8d35a42b7f34

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you plan to do with the data, it's probably the most efficient to load them into a numpy array:

```
from vtk.util import numpy_support

src_points = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(polydata.GetPoints().GetData())
```

Also python's builtin help is very useful with VTK.

```
import vtk
polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

help(vtk)
help(polydata)
```